# Copy items from Calendar list in each subsite to Calendar list in root site in SharePoint Online using CSOM PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, calendar

I am trying to copy all items from Calendar list in each sub-site to the Calendar list in root site.

Here are my thoughts. Is it possible to make a CSOM PowerShell script for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The structure seems to be fine and here is a sample script to copy list items between sharepoint lists： [SharePoint Online: Copy List Item to Another List using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/01/sharepoint-online-copy-list-items-to-another-list-using-powershell.html)

And of course you can have a check on the OOB approach using Calendar Overlay. [How to show a calendar from a sub-site on the home page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/257759/how-to-show-a-calendar-from-a-sub-site-on-the-home-page)